# How to handle null pointer exception using hibernate native sql query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a select query on five columns,one of which may or may not contain a value and as hibernate's native sql query always returns an object which is then required to convert using toString(),null pointer exception is encountered. How can i avoid this situation?

Here are the code snippets,

```
   sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT t.*,ROWNUM r FROM("+sqlQuery+") t)  WHERE r  BETWEEN " + intStartIndex + " AND " + intEndIndex;
    Query query=session.createSQLQuery(sql);  
    ArrayList<Object[]> listResult= query.list();
    return listResult;


 for(int j=0;j<arrColumnMetaData.size();j++){  //  where arrColumnMetaData stores the list returned 
   int k-0;
             Object obj[]=(Object[])arrColumnMetaData.get(j);
              childBeanObj.setNumCaptureCode(obj[k++].toString());
              childBeanObj.setTxtFileName(obj[k++].toString());
              childBeanObj.setTxtFileStatus(obj[k++].toString());
              childBeanObj.setTxtDocumentCode(obj[k++].toString()); 
}
```

i am doing something like this.. kindly tell if this is  the right approach or suggest if u have a better one.

Comment: You will have to make one or more null checks..

Comment: What have you tried, how are you running the query, what is the query, why do you think you are getting a null pointer exception, what does the stacktrace say.... do you want me to go on?

Comment: @JamesMassey ` do you want me to go on?` - yes please

Comment: I have tried this sqlQuery.list(), and then iterated the result. The 'sqlQuery' here is a select query working on multiple columns one of which doesn't contain a value,resulting in the null pointer.

Comment: what I meant was, post specific details about what you are doing, what you are working with, and any error messages you are getting. We can't fix your problem without more information

Comment: so when you iterate, check if the values are null and if so, do something that you think is good and safe.

Comment: Apply null check thats it on list and if it is null then handle that accordingly

Comment: @james massey i have the posted the code snippets in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (obj[k+1] != null){ // check for null, not null then .toString() method

       childBeanObj.setNumCaptureCode(obj[k++].toString());
       childBeanObj.setTxtFileName(obj[k++].toString());
       childBeanObj.setTxtFileStatus(obj[k++].toString());
       childBeanObj.setTxtDocumentCode(obj[k++].toString()); 
    }
```